# Iterating through an array of divs

Tags: javascript, html, css

Im still new at javascript ive been learning the concepts for several months and this is my first time taking a crack at it.

Im trying to create a carousel using css3 and Javascript (no Jquery)

the console keeps throwing an error.

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property `display` of undefined

The following is my html and javascript code

```js
var slideShow = document.querySelectorAll('.inside');

for (var i = 0; i < slideShow.length; i++) {
  setTimeout(function() {
    slideShow[i].display.style = 'inline-block';
  }, 2000)
}
```

```html
<div class="inside">
  <div class="inner1">
    <h1>This is Inner div 1</h1>
  </div>
  <div class="inner2">
    <h1>This is Inner div2</h1>
  </div>
  <div class="inner3">
    <h1>This is Inner div3</h1>
  </div>
  <div class="inner4">
    <h1>This is Inner div4</h1>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Aside from `display` and `style` being in the wrong order, the problem is that by the time the `setTimeout` callback function is executed, the `for` loop has already ended, and `i` is equal to the length of the nodeList (and since the last element's index is one less than the length of the nodeList, an error is thrown).

You could capture the value of `i` in an [IIFE](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Immediately-invoked_function_expression):

[**Example Here**](http://jsfiddle.net/7ffc70pj/)

```
var slideShow = document.querySelectorAll('.inside');

for (var i = 0; i < slideShow.length; i++) {
  (function (i) {
    setTimeout(function () {
      slideShow[i].style.display = 'inline-block';
    }, 2000 * (i + 1));
  })(i);
}
```

or you could use the [`.forEach()` method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach):

[**Example Here**](http://jsfiddle.net/2L0oLm1L/)

```
var slideShow = document.querySelectorAll('.inside');

Array.prototype.forEach.call(slideShow, function (el, i) {
  setTimeout(function () {
    el.style.display = 'inline-block';
  }, 2000 * (i + 1));
});
```

---

Alternatively, you could just use `setInterval`:

[**Example Here**](http://jsfiddle.net/zw6za21b/)

```
var slideShow = document.querySelectorAll('.inside');
var i = 0;
var interval = setInterval(function () {
  if (i < slideShow.length) {
    slideShow[i].style.display = 'inline-block';
    i++;
  } else {
    clearInterval(interval);
  }
}, 2000);
```

Comment: True, and also looks like OP wants to change the display gradually, not all at once, so for this you can change the fixed 2000 to `2000 * (i + 1)`

Comment: no error throws, but it doesnt change style of the divs the other three still remain hidden, I applogize i really should have posted the css to

Comment: @Veritas I updated my answer and posted 3 examples. Hopefully that helps.

Answer (score 1):

You have `display` and `style` in the wrong order.

It should be `slideShow[i].style.display='inline-block';`

Additionally, `slideShow` is only an array-like object of length 1: it contains the div `.inner` but not its children. If you want to iterate through the child elements, use

```
var slideShow = document.querySelector('.inside').children;
```

**Edit:** As Josh pointed out in a separate answer, you have another problem as well in using `setTimeout` within a for loop. By the time the function inside the timeout executes, `i` will be 4, which will give you an undefined value.

If you insist on using a for loop, you can also do this using the `forEach` method. However, `slideShow` is not technically an array, but rather an "array-like object", so it does not have its own `forEach` method. Instead, you must invoke the Array.prototype method as such:

```
[].forEach.call(slideShow, function(item) {
    setTimeout(function() {
        item.style.display = 'inline-block';
    }, 2000);
});
```

Comment: I have tried that as well it says "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'style' of undefined"

Comment: @Veritas That's because `document.querySelectorAll('.inside')` returns an array of length 1: there is only one div with class `.inside`. What it seems like you want is an array of the elements within that div. In that case, you should use `var slideShow = document.querySelector('.inside').children;`

Comment: should I use forEach?

Comment: You could use `forEach`, but a fun quirk of JavaScript is that `slideShow` is not an actual array; rather, it is an "array-like object". This means it doesn't have a `forEach` method. You can still use it though if you're clever. I updated my answer above to show how you might do this.

Comment: I was scrolling through this recently and i noticed how much you tried to help me  a year and seven months ago and i just wanted to say thank you, Ive learned alot more since then as I work with js now every day now. Just wanted to say thanks...because this issue and your answers were what got me more interested in continuing to move forward with JS

Answer (score 0):

problem is you are only selecting div.inside and it is not returning div.inner
Try this if you want to select all .inner
change class="inside" to id="inside" and copy this js

```
var slideShow=document.getElementById("inside").querySelectorAll('div');
slideShow[1].style.backgroundColor  = "red";
for (var i=0; i<slideShow.length; i++){

    setTimeout(myFun(i), 2000)

}

function myFun(i ){slideShow[i].style.display  = "inline-block";}
```